# variable in selector for click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons that should respond to a jQuery script. The buttons are to zoom and pan a svg image on a webpage. Because I want to have more than 1 svg files on a page a need my code to know which image I want to zoom. I can also use my mouse to zoom and pan (dragging), this works fine.

Short example

```
var currentID;

//get the id of the container around the image. This is: 'SVGfile' followed by a number
jQuery( ".svgcontainer" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    currentID = jQuery(this).attr('id');      
});

var target1='#zoomInButtonSVGfile1';
var target2='#panRightButton'+currentID;

jQuery(target1).click(function(){ zoomIn(); });                    //this works, but is hardcoded
jQuery("#zoomOutButtonSVGfile1").click(function(){ zoomOut(); });  //this works, but is hardcoded
jQuery(target2).click(function(){ panRight(); });                  //this doesn't work
jQuery('#panLeftButton'+currentID).click(function(){ panLeft(); });//this doesn't work
```

In the first 2 opties I don't use the variable, but hardcode it, and then it works, but it doesn't serve my purpose.
The other 2 options should works as far as I know, and after searching for options. Somehow it does nothing... Can anybody spot my mistake?

Comment: You're binding the handler when the page is loaded, not after the user clicks. `currentID` won't be set yet.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you have different pan left buttons, shouldn't they each pan the image they're associated with?

Comment: currentID is set when the mouse moves over a svgcontainer. The buttons are also inside the container. So when the user clicks on the button currentID is already set.

Comment: If the user clicks on the button, why don't you just pan that container?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to set a variable and then use it in order to bind an event, the event binding *must* also happen within the `.mousemove`.

```
jQuery( ".svgcontainer" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
   if(!jQuery(this).data("bind")){
      jQuery(this).data("bind", true);
      var currentID = jQuery(this).attr('id');    

      var target1='#zoomInButtonSVGfile1';
      var target2='#panRightButton'+currentID;

      jQuery(target1).click(function(){ zoomIn(); });
      jQuery("#zoomOutButtonSVGfile1").click(function(){ zoomOut(); });  
      jQuery(target2).click(function(){ panRight(); });                  
      jQuery('#panLeftButton'+currentID).click(function(){ panLeft(); });
   }
});
```

Comment: This will add multiple click handlers to all the elements. Every time the mouse moves, it will add another handler.

Comment: @Barmar I edited it a bit so that it only adds the event handler once. However, I'm still not lucid about the desires of the OP it might still make no sense to do this.

Comment: You could use `.one()` to bind a one-time handler.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure that's what the OP wants...binding an event at most once and *executing* it at most once are two different things.

Comment: The `.one()` method binds an event handler but only executes it once per target. Internally it does pretty much what you've written.